# Task.Run never completes when testing using a HttpClient

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, mongodb-.net-driver

Today I've run into a problem when creating a Web API using async ApiControllers.
I'm using MongoDB and since the C# driver doesn't support async, I tried to implement it in my repository layer.

The resulting method in the Building repository looked like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Building>> GetAll()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletetionSource<IEnumerable<Building>>();

    await Task.Run(() => {
        var c = this.MongoDbCollection.FindAll();
        tcs.SetResult(c);
    });

    return await tcs.Task;
}
```

Now this works perfectly when testing the repository by itself using NUnit.

But when testing from the controller (using a HttpClient) it never proceeds to the "return" line after running `tcs.SetResult(c)`. The test just keeps running until i abort it manually.

When I remove the Task.Run code and do everything synchronously then everything works as it should:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Building>> GetAll()
{
    var c = this.MongoDbCollection.FindAll();

    return c;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why I experience different behaviors when testing the **repository + database** and when testing **controller + repository + database**?

The **controller** method looks like this:
(`buildingRepository` is injected in the constructor using Ninject)

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
{
    var result = await this.buildingRepository.GetAll();
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
}
```

EDIT: Here are also the test methods. The first one is the one that's not working:
(`this.client` is a HttpClient object with the accept-header set to `"application/json"`)

```
[Test]
public void Get_WhenBuildingsExist_ShouldReturnBuilding()
{
    var task = this.client.GetAsync("/api/building/");

    var result = task.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Building>>(result);

    Assert.That(o.Any());
}

[Test]
public void Get_WhenBuildingsExist_ShouldReturnAtLeastOneBuilding()
{
    var buildings = this.buildingRepository.GetAll().Result;

    Assert.That(buildings.Any());
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by using HTTP client? Are you invoking your web application over HTTP? That would test a little more than just the controller! The whole pipline.

Comment: Looks like a synchronization context problem. When something hangs, it usually is the sync context.

Comment: Please post your actual test methods. NUnit doesn't (yet) support `async` unit tests, so you're probably blocking on the task at some point.

Comment: @usr Could you elaborate? I think you may be right, but I have no idea how to find where the problem is.

Comment: @usr Yes, the controller test tests the whole pipeline. (which is its purpose)

Comment: @StephenCleary The unit tests are not async (as you can see from the edited post), so that shouldn't be the problem. Besides, it doesn't explain why I have two different behaviors, as the methods are both async.

Comment: Can you show the action behind "/api/building/"? I'd liek to see how you call GetAll because at this point I don't have any other idea where to look.

Comment: @usr It's already posted. It's the `public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()`

Comment: @azzlack: Actually, it's best if you *do* have `async` unit tests for `async` code - but NUnit doesn't support them yet. The call to `Result` is blocking, so you may be seeing [this deadlock situation](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). I'm not familiar enough with ASP.NET pipeline unit testing to say for sure. Try changing `await Task.Run(...);` to `await Task.Run(...).ConfigureAwait(false);` (and the same for the `Get` method) - if it works, then it's that deadlock situation.

Comment: @azzlack: NUnit does support `async` unit tests now, so a better solution is to upgrade NUnit and `await` your code instead of calling `Result`.

Comment: @StephenCleary Can you post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as an accepted answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option is to upgrade to a version of NUnit that supports async unit tests, and change all `Result`/`Wait` calls to `await`:

```
[Test]
public async Task Get_WhenBuildingsExist_ShouldReturnBuilding()
{
  var content = await this.client.GetAsync("/api/building/");
  var result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Building>>(result);

  Assert.That(o.Any());
}
```

If this isn't possible (e.g., Xamarin still runs a very old version of NUnit as of this writing), then you can use [`AsyncContext` from my AsyncEx library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncContext):

```
[Test]
public void Get_WhenBuildingsExist_ShouldReturnBuilding()
{
  var o = AsyncContext.Run(async () =>
  {
    var content = await this.client.GetAsync("/api/building/");
    var result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Building>>(result);
  });

  Assert.That(o.Any());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a post I read that explains why invoking `.Results` from an asynchronous task is a bad idea but I don't have it available at the moment. Basically, you're killing the async handling by doing this. Try changing your test as follow:

```
[Test]
public void Get_WhenBuildingsExist_ShouldReturnBuilding()
{
    var task = this.client.GetAsync("/api/building/");

    var resultTask = task.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    resultTask.Wait();

    var result = resultTask.Result;
    var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Building>>(result);

    Assert.That(o.Any());
}
```

Comment: Ok. I don't understand anything now.    
I tried all your suggestions, and all of them worked.  
Then I changed back to the original implementation that didn't work - and now that one works as well!?    
Some of those controller tests were run automatically and very rapidly. Could it be that the thread pool somehow got "overworked"?

Comment: I haven't tried to dig into this since I'm focusing on understanding the new .NET 4.5 `await` feature but you may be right. I do know that using either the `.Wait()` method or the `.ContinueWith(...)` allow our unit tests to run reliably.

Comment: Sixto - do you have any pointers to find that blog post? I'm running into the same issue, and I'm trying to figure it out.

Comment: About the best explanation is in this [long blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115163.aspx) for the Async CTP. Even though it addresses WinForms and the CTP for .NET 4.5, it gives a really good explanation of what is going on inside ASP.NET and the Web API async implementation.